# How to compare two strings unarranged with a separator

Tags: php, string, compare

Lets say I have:

```
$a = "5,8,0";
$b = "8,0,5";
```

How to compare them while a regular comparison will fail, the comma separator will always be there but the order of the elements (which are `id`s of products so they are always integers) don't have to be the same (the order).

Any idea about how to do this in PHP?

Comment: @Book Of Zeus thx for the edit but any help in the answer will be better

Comment: What do you mean by comparing them? Do you want to check whether they both contain the same numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify what your end result is meant to be?

Comment: it will return true or false, the id's are joined by javascript then sent to the server so they are all integers, so i want to check for them to see if they contain the same products by comparing of the string have the same id inside them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split them into individual arrays, and then compare the two arrays.

```
$a = "5,8,0";
$b = "8,0,5";

$array_a = explode($a, ",");
$array_b = explode($b, ",");

if (count(array_diff($array_a, $array_b))===0)
    echo "The two strings contain the same values.";
else
    echo "The two strings do NOT contain the same values.";
```

Comment: so my question will become how to convert an array to a string with a defined separator ??

Comment: You can save the overhead of sorting if you compare it.

Comment: Here's the code: `function($a, $b) { $a = explode(',',$a); $b = explode(',',$b); sort($a); sort($b); return $a == $b; }`

Comment: @Qchmqs [explode()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is the function you are looking for.

Comment: almost asked how to get them back string again then i realized that this is silly,cuz i will not edit the actual strings,i will just see if they are equal lol;i will accept this question, when SO let me do so i get a message with (you can accept answer in 4 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to arrays via explode, use the result of array_intersect to determine if they are equal?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php